# Что делают ruby-файлы в React Native проекте, сгенерированном утилитой "react-native"?

Tags: ruby, react-native

Только что сгенерировал проект через `npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript`. Expo мне не подходит потому, что насколько мне извесно, этой фреймворк собирает только для Android и iOS, а я собрался запускать приложение на всех поддерживаемых платформах.

Вообще, я стараюсь не пользоваться генераторами проектов по двум причинам:

1. Много ненужного
2. Предложенная структура файлов меня как правило не устраивает

Однако методологией 100%-го ручного развёртывания React Native-проекта я пока не владею, а потому приходится чистить и реорганизовывать преложенную структуру файлов.

Первое, что бросается в глаза - это начилие файлов Ruby (**.ruby-version**,  **Gemfile**, **Gemfile.lock**). С точки зрения логики, непонятно что эти файлы делают в React Native-проекте - мне что, предлагают серверную часть написать на Ruby?

Ну и второй вопрос - можно ли все эти файлы безопасно удалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно о тех файлах, что у вас в вопросе.

Ответ можно найти в [документации, описание установки окружения разработки](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup#cocoapods). Для управления пакетами в `react-native` для Mac используется [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/), который и есть зависим от `ruby`.

Если после установки заглянуть в `Gemfile`, то там будет примерно так

```gemspec
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.7.4'

gem 'cocoapods', '~> 1.11', '>= 1.11.2'
```

Это с реального проекта. То есть мы можем увидеть, что ничего более, чем запуск `cocoapods` там нет.

Без данных файлов все прекрасно работает как в web, так Android. Но чтобы собрать проект под IOS, я использую следующую рутину

```sh
cd project/ios
pod install
# или для M1/Silicon
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

и если убрать указанные файлы, то я получу исключение с ошибкой.

То есть данные файлы используются для менеджмента пакетов, аналог для npm/yarn.

**UPD**

Например, [здесь](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#platform-ios) описано, как работает autolinking (механизм, который обнаруживает нативный код для платформы в библиотеках и использует его) для IOS. Вы можете увидеть, что процесс состоит из двух шагов, один из которых - это добавление зависимостей через `CocoaPods`.

Но и это еще не все. Я потестил и обнаружил, что в версии react > 0.64, все прекрасно работает без gem-файлов до тех пор пока не понадобятся нативные библиотеки или SDK. Я тестировал с [mapbox gl for react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps). Там есть возможность установить через `CocoaPods` или загрузить вручную SDK. В первом случае понадобились gem, во втором все прекрасно заработало без них.

#### Резюме

В зависимости от тех пакетов и библиотек, которые вы используете на IOS, вам могут понадобиться ruby файлы